# Breaking right skewed scale variable into ordinal variable

Tags: data-transformation

[image] I have multiple scale variables all with heavy right skew.  This dataset is 250,000 and I was planning to create an ordinal variable from this scale variable with 5 values.

Is it appropriate to attempt to create 5 groups with equal number of cases in each group?

In this example it would be around 50,000 in each of the 5 categories.  This would create very tight ranges on one side and very wide ranges (on the tail) for the other side.

Is this appropriate or should the group be chosen based on SD or if the range is 0-100 then each category is 20 units?

I have run the data both ways with minimal impact to the results but I would prefer to follow what is considered standard!
[image]

Comment: Any approach might do. If you have no beforehand idea, try both. There are also other approaces, such as optimal binning, in case you have a "tutor" variable which might supervise the binning (to maximize association with it).

Comment: It is a good idea to post here the histogram of your data, to see.

Comment: I just posted two different histograms with the dotted line representing the current binning to create equal n's in each group.  The company count is hard because they are whole numbers whereas the other variable is continuous.  You can see that the last group contains a lot of the high values and is very wide compared to the other data ranges.  thanks for your comments ttnphns

Comment: Why do you want to do this? One "standard" is to use the data as they come or their logarithms if skewness creates small problems.

Comment: For mapping purposes such binning can be helpful; GISes support several different automatic methods.  Otherwise, binning frequently is inferior to other procedures.  That's why we ask why you want to do it.  Regardless, we cannot possibly know what you mean by "appropriate" without having some information about the purpose and application of the results.